# I am trying to align movie cards one by one. But they are aligning according to imdb rating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The below code is the movie list component. Whenever I add a movie to the list they are arranged in a row. After 5 movies if I add the 6th one then the cards are shuffled according to the IMDb rating (descending order). Where I did do wrong?

```
const MoviesList = (props) => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
const [filterBy, setFilterBy] = useState([])
const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState('')

const movies = useSelector((state) => {
    //console.log(state.movies)
    return state.movies
})

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.value
    setSearch(inputValue)

    //filtering the movies based on the search value
    const filteredValue = movies.filter((movie) => {
        return movie.Title.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
    })
    setFilterBy(filteredValue)
}

const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setOrderBy(e.target.value)
}

const show = (movies) => {
    //sorting based on orderBy 
    switch (orderBy) {
        case 'a-z': return [].concat(movies).sort((a, b) => a.Title.localeCompare(b.Title))
        case 'z-a': return [].concat(movies).sort((a, b) => b.Title.localeCompare(a.Title))
        case '1-10': return [].concat(movies).sort((a, b) => a.imdbRating - b.imdbRating)
        case '10-1': return [].concat(movies).sort((a, b) => b.imdbRating - a.imdbRating)
        default: return [].concat(movies)
    }
}



return (
    <div className='container'>
        <div className='d-flex mb-3 '>
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center',border:'solid 3px',borderBlockColor:'bs-purple',backgroundColor:'#BFB9FA',position:'sticky' }} >My Movie List</h1>
            <form style={{ float: 'right', marginRight: '35px',top:'80px',right:'5px',position:'absolute' }}>
                <input type="text" placeholder='search by name' value={search} onChange={handleChange} className="mr-4" style={{borderRadius:7,width:'300px',padding:'3px',marginRight:'15px'}}/>
                <select value={orderBy} onChange={handleSelectChange} style={{padding:'3px',borderRadius:7,width:90}} >
                    <option value="">orderBy</option>
                    <option value="a-z">a-z</option>
                    <option value="z-a">z-a</option>
                    <option value="1-10">1-10</option>
                    <option value="10-1">10-1</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <div className="pt-2  justify-content-center " style={{textAlign:'center',width:'70%',display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: "center ",alignItems:'stretch'}}>
           
            {
                filterBy.length > 0 ? (
                    filterBy.map((movie) => {
                        return <MovieCard key={movie.imdbID} Poster={movie.Poster} Title={movie.Title} imdbRating={movie.imdbRating} imdbID={movie.imdbID} />
                    })
                ) : (
                    show(movies).map((movie) => {
                        return <MovieCard key={movie.imdbID} {...movie} />
                    })
                )
            }
        </div>

    </div >
)
}

export default MoviesList
```

[image: Here I have added 4 images]

[image: Here I have added 6 images]

Comment: This is a CSS stuff, and you don't provide anything relating to CSS in your question. Are you using bootstap grid-layout ? or flex-box?  Or your own css ?

Comment: I have used flex-box. And I don't think the issue is with CSS. The cards are aligning based on the rating.